# Guardar valor selecionado en select al buscar

Tags: php, html

tengo un pequeño formulario con un select option que me muestra diferentes opciones. Depende cual selecciones te busca unos datos en mysql u otros.
Cada vez que se realiza una busqueda el select option se cambia y se pone la primera opción envede guardar la que el usuario había puesto por si quiere hacer una segunda o tercera búsqueda.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputState">Server</label>
      <select name="server" id="server" class="form-control" >
        <option value="Alpha">Productos</option>
        <option value="Beta">Consumibles</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Si el usuario elige Consumibles, después de realizar la búsqueda se pone productos envede conservar lo seleccionado por el usuario.

Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Para eso hay un atributo llamado `selected` y con un `if` en php puedes resolverlo. Algo parecido a esto:

```
if variable == "Beta" {
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputState">Server</label>
      <select name="server" id="server" class="form-control" >
        <option value="Alpha">Productos</option>
        <option value="Beta" selected>Consumibles</option>
      </select>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Beta es un string, colocarlo así no dará error?

Comment: @BetaM lo he editado.